# What makes @ required in some CSS selectors?

Tags: css, css-selectors

In CSS selectors, sometimes `@` is used, such as in `@media` and `@font-face`. What happens behind the scenes that makes the `@` required?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are what know as an at-rule, you can view the documentation [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/At-rule). This is because they aren't ruled sets where they just apply styles in the normal sense. It doesn't target 1 group of elements. It either has rule sets nested in them or input styles into the program such as `@font-face`.

Comment: For additional clarity: at-rules are *not* selectors.